# Align a font-awesome icon in one line with label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

How to align a font-awesome icon in one line with checkbox and label?

Now I have this
[image]

And I want to have `[]` `state` `?`

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> state
          </label>
          <i class="fa fa-question-circle"
            aria-hidden="true"
            uib-popover="it is state"
            popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `i` tag inside the label.

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox"> state
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"
                aria-hidden="true"
                uib-popover="it is state"
                popover-trigger="'mouseenter'">a</i>
              </label>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

or add `class='text-nowrap'`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-nowrap">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> state
          </label>
          <i class="fa fa-question-circle"
            aria-hidden="true"
            uib-popover="it is state"
            popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```